# php system('npm install') not working

Tags: php, npm, exec, system, shell-exec

I want to install npm in a directory using PHP.
I use this command to install npm:

```
system('npm install', $output);
```

Then I get the following response: 127
Which means, if I looked it up correctly, that the npm command is not found. I've also tried `npm -v`, this also gives the 127 response.
My PHP is running on the same user as I use in my terminal. When I run `npm install` or `npm -v` in my terminal it's working fine.

Any ideas what could be the problem?
NPM is installed in `/usr/local/bin/` which is included in my `$PATH` variable.

Comment: Is 127 the return value of `system()` or the content of the variable `$output`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Still not sure why I have to add this to my command in PHP but this worked for me:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/npm; npm install
```

Ofcourse, simple explanation would be that NPM is now in my `PATH` variable, but `echo $PATH` did already return that directory.

Answer (score 1):

I recently used system command via console myself. I found

```
chdir('/usr/local/bin/');
```

a useful function to change directory. Please put this before your system call.

If you are using an old version of PHP (below 5.4) you can try to turn safe_mode to off. See this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php).

Use the full path in the command, like:

```
system('/usr/local/bin/npm install', $output);
```

Then please check if the apache user has the permissions to find (or get to) and execute the command. I think it is an permission problem.

If you are using SELiunux you can set the mode to "Permissive" by using `setenforce 0`. If it works you have to grant the apache user access. Do not forget to turn the enforcing level back to "Enforcing" by using `setenforce 1`.

Comment: Tried that as well without any luck

Comment: @SheperdOfFire I added some more ideas.

Comment: @Phillipp Thanks for your time. I've solved the problem myself in the end. Still not sure why it worked but I've posted my answer.